# React Native Modal is not drawn below the StatusBar on Android

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

In React Native (With EXPO), I'm showing a Modal.
The Modal gets drawn behind the StatusBar in iOS but it's not happening on Android.

Do you know why? I could not find any solution for this.

The StatusBar has already set the `translucent={true}` prop. That's why you are able to see the Map behind the StatusBar on Android. But I can not draw the Modal component behind it (as I can do on iOS).

Here I add a couple of screenshots and an online viewer to check this behavior: https://snack.expo.io/BJR4oF4A7

Another weird behavior that I'm seeing is that it doesn't matter which `translucent` value I set, it always works in the same way (it's always translucent, even when I set it to `false`).

In case that this is impossible, how can I set the background to #FFF and the font-color to #000 on the StatusBar on Android?

I want to know:

1. Why there are different behaviors in iOS and Android.
2. Why changing the props of `StatusBar` still not changing its behavior (can be seen in the online viewer, changing `translucent`, or `backgroundColor` values)
3. If it's impossible to get the modal drawn behind the StatusBar, so, how can I change the background and the font-color of it when a Modal is opened? (in Android) (with no hiding it)

**Android**
[image: Android]

**iOS**
[image: iOS]

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

2. I believe you need to try the app as a standalone application, not using the Expo client. It somehow sometimes has hard time dealing with StatusBar (I've already experienced it too).
3. You may use the `hidden` property that is working on both platforms, based on your current state: `<StatusBar hidden={!!this.state.isModalShown} />`

This will simply hide the status bar whenever your modal is opened.

Comment: I should try on the standalone app. True. On another hand, I don't want to hide the StatusBar, I just want to change the font-color to #000 and the background color to #FFF

Comment: For your first question, after checking their implementation, I believe it's related to the iOS "presentationStyle" property

Answer (score 0):

Set the barStyle to be the contrasting backgroundColor.

Black writing on white background, so have dark-content on white status bar.

```
<StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor={"#fff"} />
```